# Add formating to custom views's field (to remove sourounding quotes for the JSON values)

Tags: 8, views

My custom views field returns JSON as a string:

```
"order_line_items": "[{"sku":"GC2","quantity":"5.00","price":"50.00"},{"sku":"SGBLEND","quantity":"1.00","price":"6.00"},{"sku":"NAV1STYR","quantity":"1.00","price":"9.50"}]",
```

I hope to get rid of the surrounding quotation (") marks.

This is how the field is created

```
class OrderLineItems extends FieldPluginBase {

  public function usesGroupBy() {
    return FALSE;
  }

  public function query() {
    // Do nothing -- to override the parent query.
  }

  public function render(ResultRow $values) {
    $order = $this->getEntity($values);
    
    $details = [];
    
    foreach ($order->getItems() as $order_item) {
      $product_sku = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity()->getSku();
      $product_quantity = $order_item->getQuantity();
      $product_price = $order_item->getUnitPrice()->getNumber();
      
      $order_item_array = [
        'sku' => $product_sku,
        'quantity' => $product_quantity,
        'price' => number_format((float)$product_price, 2, '.', '')
      ];
     $details[] = $order_item_array;
    }
    return json_encode($details);
    return $details;
  }
}
```

I haven't found how can I add a formatter for this custom field, to make this the JSON output valid. I did some research and I have found that there are modules that can do this for real fields, but not for this kind of custom views fields.

https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_views

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using custom views serializer. Here is the guide:

https://www.paralleldevs.com/blog/how-create-custom-views-serializer-drupal-8-or-9

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).